# How to remove tags before dot in classes?

Tags: awk, sed, gsub

A file has following list:

```
abc.class1 def.class2 ghi.class1.class2 .class1.class2 
abc.class3 def.class4 ghi.class3.class4 .class3.class4
```

expected output:

```
.class1 .class2 .class1.class2 .class1.class2
.class3 .class4 .class3.class4 .class3.class4
```

Using following sed command

```
sed 's/^.*\././g'
```

gives

```
output:
.class2
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `^.*\.` pattern matches a part of a string from the start till the last occurrence of a literal `.` in the string, so in the end, this whole part of a line is removed (together with a dot).

You can use

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='abc.class1 def.class2 ghi.class1.class2 .class1.class2 
abc.class3 def.class4 ghi.class3.class4 .class3.class4'
sed -E 's/( |^)[^ .]+\./\1./g'  <<< "$s"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/ynDKLu). The POSIX ERE regex matches

- `( |^)` - Group 1 (`\1`): a space or start of string
- `[^ .]+` - one or more chars other than space and dot
- `\.` - a literal `.` char.

Each match is replaced with Group 1 value + `.`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to trim the strings field by field if they don't start with `.`:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(/^[^.]*\./,".",$i)} 1' file
.class1 .class2 .class1.class2 .class1.class2
.class3 .class4 .class3.class4 .class3.class4
```

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` approach using `match` and `substr`

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){match($i,"\.c"); $i=substr($i,RSTART,length($i))}}1' file
.class1 .class2 .class1.class2 .class1.class2
.class3 .class4 .class3.class4 .class3.class4
```

Answer (score 1):

With a sed that has `-E` for EREs, e.g. GNU or BSD seds:

```
$ sed -E 's/(^| )[^.]+/\1/g' file
.class1 .class2 .class1.class2 .class1.class2
.class3 .class4 .class3.class4 .class3.class4
```

otherwise with any sed:

```
$ sed 's/^[^.]*//; s/ [^.]*/ /g' file
.class1 .class2 .class1.class2 .class1.class2
.class3 .class4 .class3.class4 .class3.class4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/[^.]*\(\.[^ ]* \)/\1/g' input_file
.class1 .class2 .class1.class2 .class1.class2
.class3 .class4 .class3.class4 .class3.class4
```

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
abc.class1 def.class2 ghi.class1.class2 .class1.class2 
abc.class3 def.class4 ghi.class3.class4 .class3.class4
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="\\.[^ ]*"}{$1=$1;print}' file.txt
```

output

```
.class1 .class2 .class1.class2 .class1.class2
.class3 .class4 .class3.class4 .class3.class4
```

Explanation: use `FPAT` (field pattern) to inform AWK that field is literal `.` followed by zero or more non-spaces. `$1=$1` triggers line rebuild, `print` does print said line.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk -F. -v OFS=. -v RS='[[:space:]]' '{ $1 = ""; printf "%s", $0 RT }' file
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `awk` with `gsub()` function:

```
awk '{gsub(/[[:alpha:]]+\./,".")} 1' file
.class1 .class2 .class1.class2 .class1.class2
.class3 .class4 .class3.class4 .class3.class4
```

- or GNU `awk` `gensub()` function:

```
awk '{print gensub(/[[:alpha:]]+\./,".","g")}' file
.class1 .class2 .class1.class2 .class1.class2
.class3 .class4 .class3.class4 .class3.class4
```